# Is there a good field methods book that covers terrestrial ecology?

Tags: ecology

In the past I have used [Limnological Analysis](http://www.springer.com/life+sciences/ecology/book/978-0-387-98928-0) by Wetzel and Likens and [Methods in Stream Ecology](http://store.elsevier.com/Methods-in-Stream-Ecology/Richard-Hauer/isbn-9780123329073/) edited by Hauer and Lamberti to develop labs and research methods for courses and projects with an aquatic focus.

These books detail the standard methods of lotic and lentic ecology with some emphasis on utilizing the methods in undergraduate or graduate level courses.

I am now developing a biogeochemistry course that is not limited to aquatic systems and I am looking for a summary of field methods for terrestrial systems.

Is there a book that summarizes terrestrial field ecology methods similar to Wetzel and Likens and Hauer and Lamberti?

Comment: I'd be curious to know if the book I suggested (Methods in Ecosystem Science) meets your needs, or if you find an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Methods in Ecosystem Science](http://books.google.com/books/about/Methods_in_Ecosystem_Science.html?id=N_pGrSntap0C) edited by Oswaldo Sala, Rob Jackson, Hal Mooney, and Robert Howarth is a classic standard reference used by many (most?) ecosystem ecologists.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Field and Laboratory Methods for General Ecology](http://books.google.com/books/about/Field_and_laboratory_methods_for_general.html?id=WFfwAAAAMAAJ) by James E. Brower, Jerrold H. Zar, and Carl N. von Ende.

If you are only interested in plant sampling techniques, an great resource published by U.S. Bureau of Land Management is [Measuring & Monitoring Plant Populations](http://www.blm.gov/nstc/library/pdf/MeasAndMon.pdf) by Caryl L. Elzinga, Daniel W. Salzer, and John W. Willoughby.

Another great resource that covers wildlife research and management techniques (2 volume set) is [The Wildlife Techniques Manual](http://joomla.wildlife.org/techniquesmanual/) published by The Wildlife Society and edited by Nova J. Silvy.